# Issues using PHP Trader Functions: Call to undefined function trader_ma()

Tags: php, macos, unix, pear, pecl

I'm attempting to install the Trader extension on my mac. I believe the install was done correctly but can't seem to use them. Here is my feedback from terminal

> sudo  pecl install trader
>
> pecl/trader is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.4.0
>
> install failed

Based on that it shows that I have installed it. But here is what I get when trying to use one

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function trader_cci()

Anybody have tips on a step I may have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @shenn did you get any solution for this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Did you include the extension in your php.ini file? You will need to add the following line in the correct ini (depends on if you use it on the command line or via FPM) to tell PHP that it needs to load the installed extension

```
extension=trader.so
```

Comment: This is not the issue. I having the same issue